# Context in sms cannot be applied

Tags: android

I get an error on a code that was working until last year.
Now I need to modify the code to add some features and get the error "*Context in sms cannot be applied*"

```
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getContext()); //<-Context in sms cannot be applied
```

I tried by changing the API level to 19 but I get an error in the Gradle app file

Also tried

```
String defaultSmsPackageName = String.valueOf(smsManager.getCarrierConfigValues());
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(java.security.AccessControlContext());
String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage();
```

And always get an error.

I'm working on Android Studio.

Comment: please add your error log

Comment: @SabbirAhmed There's no error log, the error is not in running time but in developing time. Now I tried to change getContext() to this.getApplicationContext() and compile but it gets run time error. __java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference__

Comment: @SabbirAhmed Now I moved the code From MainActivity to the Fragment class and seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This call does not work because before API 19 there are no "default sms package".

Context: context of the requesting application, so if you are calling this from Activity then try using "this" directly.